# Is a single Python executable file shared by all clients when run on a server?

Tags: python, django, heroku, tornado

I've been working with a Tornado project on my local machine by running server.py. When deployed to the server (e.g. Heroku), will a single instance of server.py be shared by all clients or will each client have their own running version? I am wondering this because I am thinking of making use of global variables in server.py and wondering if they will be shared across all clients or just a single client.

Comment: The file and the process are different things. Different processes may share the same executable file without sharing global variables, stdin/out, or other global state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The execution flow should be the same when you run it on your local machine. Take the following code:-

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

print 'This is executed only once and global'
name = 'myname'

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    print 'This is executed only once'
    def get(self):
        print 'This is executed for each requests'
        self.write("Hello, world %s " % name)

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

When, we'll get the following output:-

```
$ ./bin/python server.py 
This is executed only once and global
This is executed only once



This is executed for each requests
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /favicon.ico (::1) 0.52ms
This is executed for each requests
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /favicon.ico (::1) 0.25ms
```

This mean the code outside the class body will be executed every time the server start and any state will stay there until it being restarted. When the server was started, it also instantiate the class `MainHandler` and for each incoming requests, the `get` method on the instance get called. This mean the code in the class body will also being executed once and only the code in the method `get` will get a fresh state for each incoming requests. I assume 'client' in your question mean incoming web requests.

Usually in normal python wsgi application, the way to keep some shared state between function without explicitly passing parameters down the chain is to use the thread-local object. I don't know much about tornado but from a brief read it seem doesn't run inside thread so you have to consult the docs to find out the recommended way of sharing state between functions.

Answer (score 1):

Each client will have their own running version. Definitely. 
If you want to have some sort of global variables, you should use some inter-process communication tools (message passing, synchronization, shared memory, or rpc). Redis, for example.

Comment: This is true of PHP-style environments, but in Tornado one process will serve multiple clients at once.

Answer (score 0):

With Tornado you'll have at least one process per machine/VM (Heroku calls these "dynos"); in multicore environments you'll want to run multiple processes per machine (one per core).  Each process handles many users, so in the simple case where there is only one process you can use global variables to share state between users, although as you grow to multiple dynos and processes you'll need some sort of inter-process communication.